# How i can get version kurento media server?

Tags: video-streaming, kurento

Which command print version kurento media server?
May be like this `etc/init.d/kurento-media-server-6.0 version`
And how i can get other info: all work streams ( now transcoding ), get info a specific stream ? From directly KMS ....

Answer (score 4):

Version can be taken from package manager:

```
dpkg-query -l kurento-media-server | awk '$1 == "ii" { print $3; exit }'
```